# Distributed sessions with GlassFish

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I work with Glassfish 4.0.I want to do following:

I have two components A and B...

1. User logs into one of the component A using Web browser;
2. User then goes to another component B;
3. User should not have to login again.

Basically, the session created in A should be used in B.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you tried something? If yes show us.

Comment: I am interested if it is possible  to share data two java web application

Comment: I have added tags `java` and `java-ee`. The tags in a question are sometimes the most important information because it heads your question to the aimed public. The tags `session` and `glassfish` have a small number of followers,  because of this your question was seen so little..

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you want to have some sort of **Single Sign-On**. Have a look here for a description using an authentication realm in GlassFish: [User Authentication for Single Sign-on](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beacq.html)

The blog post [Session Sharing between Java Web Applications](http://www.eteration.com/session-sharing-between-java-web-applications/) explains how to not violate standards (Servlet, Java EE) and advises to use some backend like Memcached.